# When using libmongoc i get a segfault at `client = mongoc_client_new ("mongodb://localhost:27017");`

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

When I try to use libmongoc, I get a segfault at

```
client = mongoc_client_new ("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

GDB results:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7970d79 in _mongoc_client_new_from_uri () from 
/usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
(gdb) backtrace
0  0x00007ffff7970d79 in _mongoc_client_new_from_uri () from 
/usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff7970e57 in mongoc_client_new () from /usr/local/lib/libmongoc- 
1.0.so.0
#2  0x0000000000401632 in handlerMain (UID=0x7fffffffe420 "12\n") at 
handler.c:57
#3  0x0000000000402e70 in reciever (run=1) at server.c:61
#4  0x0000000000402fd8 in main () at server.c:89
```

I've tried a lot of things, but am so far unsucessfull in solving the issue.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
It doesn't seem to be a problem with my code, as far as I know I'm calling `mongc_client_new` correctly.

```
Core was generated by ./server.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0  0x00007fd680bb1d79 in _mongoc_client_new_from_uri () from /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007fd680bb1d79 in _mongoc_client_new_from_uri () from /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#1  0x00007fd680bb1e57 in mongoc_client_new () from /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#2  0x0000000000401646 in handlerMain (UID=0x7ffe76514530 "8fc1ae29") at handler.c:59
#3  0x0000000000402e9d in reciever (run=1) at server.c:62
#4  0x0000000000403005 in main () at server.c:90
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007fd680bb1e57 in mongoc_client_new () from /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0
(gdb) up
#2  0x0000000000401646 in handlerMain (UID=0x7ffe76514530 "8fc1ae29") at handler.c:59
59              client = mongoc_client_new (uri_str);
(gdb) print uri_str
$1 = 0x4030dc "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
```

Comment: Does this happen immediately or after 30 seconds or so? Is there a `mongod` process listening on 27017 on the local machine?

Comment: It happens immediately, 
`netstat -tulpn` outputs `tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:27017 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 15127/mongod`

Comment: I'm running the exact same code on a different pc and it works just fine, Maybe there's a problem with the installation, but i've reinstalled it multiple times already

Comment: If this code works on one system and not another, it would be prudent to ask "what's different?"

Comment: I wish I knew, I followed the exact same steps. The only difference is that the one that works is on a laptop and the one that doesn't work is on a VPS

Comment: It's hard to say without poking around the system, but i would look at things that affect connectivity, perhaps one has auth enabled and the other does not? one has a firewall and the other does not?

Comment: I'm trying to find a difference, but can't find any. What error would I normally get if the specified ip was incorrect? No matter what I enter, i still get the same error.

Comment: @PeteGarafano The edit doesn't clarify things for me, but maybe it's useful to you.